# Add AdMob in MAUI by Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite

Tags: c#, admob, maui

I am trying to implement AdMob for my application. I need Banners, Full screen, and Native ads.
I was able to create full screen and banner ads by this Nuget https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob.
But unfortunately it don't contains native ads.

So I am trying to rewrite the implementations from the tutorial for Xamarin with Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite Nuget. But there are things here that I don't know how to change.

Code which I trying to rewrite:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        //add test ads and we will remove after upload :::
           RequestConfiguration.Builder builder = new RequestConfiguration.Builder();
        builder = builder.SetTestDeviceIds(new string[] { "your id in output" });
        MobileAds.RequestConfiguration = builder.Build();



        Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext);
        //
        LoadApplication(new App());
        
    }
```

When I change `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` -> `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.Init()` I don't see overwrite which accepts this parameters.

I am not sure what should I put there `builder = builder.SetTestDeviceIds(new string[] { "your id in output" });` Should I add Banner, Full screen and Native ads Id?

And `LoadApplication(new App());` don't exist in MAUI.

Is anyone able to solve my problem or provide an example implementation for MAUI?

Comment: The NuGet Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite applies to Xamarin.Android, not for MAUI. I searched the information about AdMob in MAUI and found that only this NuGet Package Plugin.MauiMTAdmob can help. You can check this tutorial: [Admob for MAUI made easy](https://www.mauiexpert.it/admob-for-maui-made-easy/). Wish it can help you.

Comment: You can also put forward [requirement](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Some package which are for Xamarin work in MAUI so I hoped it will work also ;/

Comment: You got that right.